# Adding a JLabel to a JMapViewer

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jmapviewer

Hello I am trying to add a `JLabel` to a `JMapViewer`, my current code is

```
 JLabel label = new JLabel(jlabels[x]);
        Point point = map.getMapPosition(lat, lng, false);
        map.add(label);
        label.setLocation(point);
        MapMarker marker = new MapMarkerDot(lat, lng);
        map.addMapMarker(marker);
        map.validate();
        map.repaint();
```

However it won't seem to add the label at all. I am no sure what else I could do to make it work. There are a few other questions like this but none have any answers so was wondering if anyone could help?

Comment: Not sure if it wild make a difference, but you've not set the size of label

Comment: @MadProgrammer good shout, just tried it and it didn't change anything. thanks though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `JMapViewer extends JPanel` and invokes `setLayout(null)`. Absent something equivalent to `label.setBounds()`, the label will never appear. Instead, leverage one of the `MapMarkerDot` constructors that admits a label string:

```
Coordinate paris = new Coordinate(48.8567, 2.3508);
map.addMapMarker(new MapMarkerDot("Paris", paris));
```